# Windows 10 and PHP a file_get_contents() responds with permission denied

Tags: php, windows, xampp

#### Error:

`Warning: file_get_contents(C:\Users\ET\projects\results.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Users\ET\projects\results.php on line 16`

- line 16:  `$fileContents = file_get_contents("Files/$file","r");`
- XAMPP with PHP 7.3
- IntelliJ PHPStorm 2019.2.3
- Windows 10 Home

This fails in both the IntelliJ IDE's terminal, in CMD and in CMD opened as admin.

How is this fixed in windows where there is no `chmod`?

Comment: I have the same issue, could you fix it?

Answer (score -3):

Copy your project files to (it is xampp documents folder: c:/xampp/htdocs for (php,html,css,js)):

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/proj1
c:/xampp/htdocs/proj2
```

Then set virtualhost: C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/proj1"
ServerName proj1.xx
ServerAlias www.proj1.xx
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/proj1">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/proj2"
ServerName proj2.xx
ServerAlias www.proj2.xx
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/proj2">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Create in windows hosts file: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1 localhost proj1.xx proj2.xx
```

Restart xampp apache2, browser and then run in browser:

http://proj1.xx

Or

http://proj2.xx

You can change **c:/xampp/htdocs/proj1** to your project path **C:\Users\ET\projects** ofcourse in xampp virtualhosts file.

P.S. You don't know the basics ... read and learn.

Comment: thanks for the invested time and letting me know that I don't know the basics, yet this has nothing to do with apache but with PHP and users/app/permissions, please read the question again.